# Omnifaces no current representation for target resource

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, servlets, omnifaces

I try recreating this example https://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket into my server.

I have currently omnifaces-1.6.3.jar installed but socket doesn't work properly because it throws

> classNotFoundException org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext

which is normal because PushContext is after 2.3 version of omnifaces.

But when i throw omnifaces-3.12.jar or omnifaces-2.3.jar into my WEB-INF/lib folder and remove the previous omnifaces jars , server throws:

> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Any ideas to fix that?`How can i make my server recognize these?

My configurations are:

JSF 2.3
Primefaces 8.0
Tomcat 8.5.57.0
Servlet 3.1
Java 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my Tomcat version was incompatible with those particulat versions. I installed omnifaces-3.1.jar and it worked corrrectly.